# Mesos not creating containers on Weave network

Tags: kubernetes, mesos, weave

I'm working with Kubernetes on Mesos, with Weave as an overlay network. I'm trying to get Mesos to create it's Docker containers on the Weave network, but for some reason I'm failing. I've created an `/etc/mesos-slave/executor_environment_variables` file on each slave that sets the `DOCKER_HOST` env var to the Weave socket, but Mesos doesn't seem to pick it up. I've neglected using the static Weave bridge for this as that is no longer recommended, but Mesos doesn't seem to want to cooperate, so that's my next step.

- Kubernetes 1.2
- Mesos 0.25.0
- Weave 1.3.1

Comment: Any particular reasons you wish to use Weave 1.3.1? ...Latest release is 1.4.4. Also, Kubernetes 1.2 isn't out yet, and Mesos 0.27 is out. This is just a note, the versions shouldn't matter very much.

Comment: You're right, I've since upgraded to Weave 1.4.1 I believe. I've upgraded the versions on both Weave and Mesos (0.27) but it hasn't changed anything yet.

Comment: I'll need more info on what you have done to give you an answer, it's probably easier to chat on slack and post the answer here later, what do you think?